# Can I resolve a function scoped deferred object or do I have to pass the deferred in?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to have a function that creates its own Deferred object, and when the function has Deferred.resolved proceed with the Deferred.then method? Or do I have to create the Deferred object outside the function, pass it in then return the resolved object?

**JS**

```
function hide() {
    $.when(fadeElementOut(this.$el)).then(() => this.dispose());
}

function fadeElementOut($el) {
            if($el) {
                let $deferred = $.Deferred();
                $el.addClass(config.stateClasses.hidden);

                $el.on('transitionend', (event) => {
                    if(event.originalEvent.propertyName === 'opacity') {
                        return $deferred.resolve();
                    }
                });
            }
    }
```

Comment: have you tried fadeElementOut(this.$el).then(() => this.dispose());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's not only possible but also advised to create the deferred object inside the function that will eventually cause it to resolve. However, `$.when` will not magically detect the existence of the deferred, instead you have to `return` the deferred's promise:

```
function hide() {
    fadeElementOut(this.$el).then(() => this.dispose());
}

function fadeElementOut($el) {
    const deferred = $.Deferred();
    if ($el) {
        $el.addClass(config.stateClasses.hidden);
        $el.on('transitionend', event => {
            if (event.originalEvent.propertyName === 'opacity') {
                deferred.resolve();
                // a `return` here is pointless
            }
        });
    } else {
        deferred.resolve(); // when there is no element, fulfill the promise immeidately
    }
    return deferred.promise();
//  ^^^^^^
}
```

Comment: Ahh, yeah this makes more sense!! Thank you!